# content get disappear when i open console window

Tags: jquery, dictionary, tabs, slider

I am using bootstrap tab functionality in that one tab have photo gallery slider and other one have the map.When  by default I open the page, the map didn't load but when I open console window using f12, the map appears properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean google map, this how you load google map:

1- include this script tag at the head:

`<script type="text/javascript" src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>`

2- include this code too, make sure to change 'WebsiteTitle' to yours:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>function initialize(cord1, cord2) { var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cord1, cord2); var myOptions = { zoom: 16, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }; var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Map_Panel_Id'), myOptions); var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng, map: map, title: 'WebsiteTitle' }); }</script>
```

3- insert div tag with the 'Map_Panel_Id' like that where you want the map to be shown. change the coordinate to yours:

```
<div id="Map_Panel_Id"><script type='text/javascript'>initialize(@mapLatitude, @mapLongitude);</script></div>
```

if this doesn't fix your problem, please give us a link for your page.

Comment: Please don't answer with any assumptions.